# Weird if-else behaviour Javascript

Tags: javascript, loops

The else-statement below never executes even if the if-statement is false. I think I've made some very basic mistake but can't figure out what.

```
var a = ["king","queen","100"];
    for (var i=0; i<a.length; i++) {
        if (a[i] === "king" || "queen"){
            console.log("monarch");
        }
        else {
            console.log("The number is: "+ parseInt(a[i]));
        }
    }
// This prints out "monarch" 3 times
```

Comment: "queen" is a truthy value. Do this `a[i] === "king" || a[i] === "queen"`

Comment: thanks it worked but shouldn't both king and queen be false for a[2]

Comment: Yes `a[2] === "king" || a[2] === "queen"` is `false`.

Comment: you do not need `parseInt(a[i])`, because you add a string to the string.

Comment: Take note, when you say `a[i] === "king" || "queen"` you are asking if a[i] equals to "king", and after you ask another question, literaly `"queen"`, but you want to ask `a[i]==="queen"`. so your conditional should be like @OriDrori says

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be:

```
var a = ["king","queen","100"];
for (var i=0; i<a.length; i++) {
    if (a[i] === "king" || a[i] ===  "queen"){
        console.log("monarch");
    }
    else {
        console.log("The number is: "+ parseInt(a[i]));
    }
}
```

You wrote your boolean expression the way we would speak a spoken language, *"A is either 1 or 2"*.  That's not the way the `OR` is interpreted.

Either the left side of the `OR` is `true`: `a[i] === "king"` is `true`;  or the right side of the `OR` is `true`: `"queen"`. It's evaluating the string by itself, and the string `"queen"` is not `null`, so it evaluates to `true`.

Comment: so you mean the way javascript checks the condition is : either a[i]="king" or "queen" in which case for a[2] the if a[2]="king" is false but if the lone ("queen") is still correct right?

Comment: @BijayTimilsina exactly!

Comment: @TiagoMarinho - nice edits, thanks for the additional clarification.

Answer (score 0):

You gotta make your two conditions separately with `||` as follow: `a[i] === "king" || a[i] ===  "queen"`